# Find the number of rearrangements of AABBCCDDEE such that each of the following conditions is satisfied.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

a) The two As appear next to each other.

My Answer: Glue the A's together to get: $$\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$$

b) The two As are separated.

My answer: Take the complement: $$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}-\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$$

c) The four vowels (A,A,E,E) are all separated.

My answer: $$\binom{7}{4}$$ for the A's and E's? And the rest I'm a little stuck on.

I think I got parts a) and b) correctly, but if someone could double check that would be great. Part c) is where I need help. I'm not sure exactly what I need to do there.

Comment: What exactly does "all separated" mean?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm not 100% sure. I thought it meant the vowels are separated by B's, C's and D's. However I could mean they are a separate problem. Kind of like the answer given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) and b) look good

There are $\binom 62 \binom 42 \binom 22 $ ways to arrange the 6 consonants

for each of these you have 7 places to put the vowels -

$\binom 72$ ways to place the A's and then $\binom 52$ to place the E's for a total of

$$  N =  \binom 62 \binom 42 \binom 22\binom 72 \binom 52  $$

Comment: I think you mean $\binom{5}{2}$ to replace the E's

Comment: thanks - I have edited my answer